# Universal function to get KeyPress Events from TextBoxes

Tags: .net, winforms, textbox, event-handling

my problem is the following:

In my C# Windows Forms program I have about 50 Text Boxes. They all may only contain numbers from 1 to 1024. 
So I actually have two issues:

1. Is there a way to get a general "KeyPress Event", so I can intercept the Input for every text Box in one function ( so I dont need to write a function for every text Box ).
2. How can I limit the input to 1024? I know how to intercept letters, but how can I give the Textbox a maximum value?

Best Regards

Tobias

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Have Common Sub for a Particular Purpose To All Textboxes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6088747/how-to-have-common-sub-for-a-particular-purpose-to-all-textboxes)

Comment: As my answer to the above duplicate question explains, the *best* thing to do is create a custom control that inherits from the `TextBox` class and override the `OnKeyPress` method. Or, better yet, since you only want a number between 1 and 1024, **use a [`NumericUpDown` control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.numericupdown.aspx)**, not a `TextBox`.

Answer (score 0):

Well, since Cody did it as a comment, I'll do it as an answer.

Derive from TextEdit, and replace all occurences of TextEdit on your forms with your derived class.  In derived class, implement your restrictions with overrides.